# Best option to compress Images before uploading to s3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to compress images before uploading to aws s3 bucket for cost reduction. I am using S3Boto3Storage and have noticed that files get pushed to bucket before django model gets saved. So, to resize the image during the save will increase the inboud/outbound traffic. The other solution would be using aws lambda. But I dont know what is the best solution in terms of cost optimization

Answer (score 0):

You can override a model's `save()` method, and then use `Pillow` to reduce the quality/size of an image to compress it before pushing it to S3.

Check out [this](https://medium.com/@gajeshbhat/compress-images-during-upload-in-django-f5cedb3b0755) tutorial - it is a great resource to see how to implement image compression.

Comment: the thing is, that when I put a breakpoint on the save method. The image is already oploaded to s3 bucket.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The only way `save()` is bypassed is if the object is saved via command line, or via the admin form - both of which can be fixed by calling `save()` in `clean()`.

Comment: image = models.ImageField(storage=MediaStorage(), null=True, blank=True,
                              default='card_images/party.png')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.image = compressImage(self.image)
        return super(Events, self).save(*args, **kwargs)